# Scikit-Learn OneHotEncoder wont work as it should be?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data list that look like this:

```
[['ocak' 2017]
 ['subat' 2017]
 ['mart' 2017]
 ['nisan' 2017]
 ['mayis' 2017]
 ['haziran' 2017]
 ['temuz' 2017]
 ['agustos' 2017]
 ['eylul' 2017]
 ['ekim' 2017]
 ['kasim' 2017]
 ['aralik' 2017]
 ['ocak' 2018]
 ['subat' 2018]
 ['mart' 2018]
 ['nisan' 2018]]
```

I want to use OneHotEncoder to encode string part of the list ('subat','mart' etc..) to use it on my regression model.

The code i use is this:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

But my output is like this:

```
(0, 9)  1.0
  (0, 13)   2017.0
  (1, 10)   1.0
  (1, 13)   2017.0
  (2, 6)    1.0
  (2, 13)   2017.0
  (3, 8)    1.0
  (3, 13)   2017.0
  (4, 7)    1.0
  (4, 13)   2017.0
  (5, 4)    1.0
  (5, 13)   2017.0
  (6, 12)   1.0
  (6, 13)   2017.0
  (7, 0)    1.0
  (7, 13)   2017.0
  (8, 3)    1.0
```

which is cannot accepted by train_test_split class..

I need an output like this

```
[1.0 0.0 0.0 2017]
```

How can i make it work to give me output like above. Or is there something wrong with my code or dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneHotEncoder` returns a sparse matrix by default, so when you wrap the return value with `np.array`, you get an undesired representation. You have two options:

- Pass `sparse=False` to `OneHotEncoder` i.e,

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
```

- or convert the result to numpy array with `toarray`, i.e.,

```
X = ct.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

to get with the second way (I wrapped it into `pd.DataFrame` for easier inspection of the result):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(X)

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11      12
0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
1   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  2017.0
2   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
3   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
4   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
5   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
6   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2017.0
7   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
8   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
9   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
11  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2017.0
12  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  2018.0
13  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  2018.0
14  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2018.0
15  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  2018.0
```